# How do I implement a struct with two floats in C?

Tags: c, struct

> error: must use "struct" tag to refer to type 'point'

All I want to do is store a coordinate as a struct.
This seems maddeningly simple to do but yet I cannot do it after visiting 20 websites and scouring Kernaghan's book.

What am I  missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    struct point 
    {
        float x;
        float y;
    };

    point.x = 0.0;
    point.y = 1.9;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a *type* `struct point`, but you don't have a variable having this type.

Comment: This is just a suggestion but you should have your struct type be defined outside the main function if you would want to create an object of that struct in different functions.

Answer (score 4):

You defined a type called `struct point`, not a variable name using that definition. You'd want to either define an instance of the struct using that type:

```
struct point mypoint;  // In C, you could change mypoint to point, but that gets confusing
```

or (less common) declare variables with a type of the (possibly anonymous) struct definition by putting the name *after* the struct definition, before the semi-colon:

```
struct {
    float x;
    float y;
} point;
```

Answer (score 3):

All you've declared is a *type* named `struct point` ; you haven't created an *object* named `point` to manipulate.  You need a separate object definition, either by writing:

```
struct point {
  float x;
  float y;
};

struct point pvar;
```

or

```
struct point {
  float x;
  float y;
} pvar;
```

then you can manipulate the members of the object:

```
pvar.x = 0.0;
pvar.y = 1.9;
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

The "point" in your example is a struct tag, not a variable name.  You have declared a *type* named `struct point`, but not any variable having that type.  Where that declaration is in scope, you can declare variables having that type with the form

```
struct point my_point;
```

and then assign to their members as

```
my_point.x = 0.0;
my_point.y = 1.9;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a structure object, ie instantiate the structure.

```
struct point obj;
obj.x = 0.0;
obj.y = 1.9;
```

Other options available are

```
struct point  // Note,structure is tagged 'point' which enables multiple instantiations
    {
        float x;
        float y;
    }obj;
```

and

```
struct //  Anonymous structure with one & only one instance possible
    {
        float x;
        float y;
    }obj;
```

and finally a `typedef` which is also a common practice

```
typedef struct point 
{
  float x;
  float y;
}point;

point obj;
obj.x = 0.0;
obj.y = 1.9;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have done, is similar to saying `int = 3;` This is more like it:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    struct point {
        float x;
        float y;
    } s;

    s.x = 0.0;
    s.y = 1.9;

    return 0;
}
```

But you should see compiler warnings, because the code assigns `double` values to `float`. It is better not to use the inferior `float` type unless you are forced to.